# How do I test RSpec association in controller was set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following:

```
let(:coupon) { mock_model Coupon, code: 'special' }
let(:cart) { mock_model Cart }

it "assigns a coupon to the cart" do
  post :redeem_coupon, coupon: {coupon: coupon.code}
  assigns(:cart).coupon.should eql(coupon)
end
```

I have the following error with that:

```
 Failure/Error: assigns(:cart).coupon.should eql(coupon)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `coupon' for nil:NilClass
```

I just want to make sure the following works:

```
@cart = current_cart

if request.post?
  coupon = Coupon.find_active_by_code(params[:coupon][:coupon], @cart.subtotal, current_member)
  if coupon
    @cart.coupon = coupon
    @cart.save!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess `current_cart` is returning nil. You can stub it with the mock cart that you already created:

```
before { subject.stub(:current_cart) { cart } }
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure what subject does. But it brought me to my next error.  Mock "Cart_1002" received unexpected message :coupon with (no args) Which sounds right. But doing a coupon.should_receive(:coupon) didn't work. Also, how is subject somehow aware of current object? (Is subject the controller?)

Comment: nvm I made it work. was supposed to be cart.should_receive(:coupon).and_return(coupon) thanks!

Comment: How come this wouldn't work?     it "redirects to the cart_path" do
      Coupon.any_instance.stub(:find_active_by_code).and_return(coupon)
      cart.should_receive(:save!).and_return(true)
      post :redeem_coupon, coupon: {coupon: coupon.code}
    end
 (Mock "Cart_1002").save!(any args)
           expected: 1 time
           received: 0 times

Comment: Yes the subject is generally an instance of the thing being described. So if you `describe MyController` its an instance of your controller class. rspec-rails does some more setup for controller tests, its a bit more than just `MyController.new`, for example it stubs out view rendering and gives you convenient methods like `post` and `assigns`.

Comment: In think the code in your third comment won't work because you are stubbing an instance method (of `Coupon`) instead of the `find_active_by_code` class method. Try `Coupon.stub(:find_active_by_code)...`